# Sed command cannot find my regex

Tags: regex, linux, bash, oracle

I have to "clean" some oracle DDL scrpits, removing tablespace declaration and i have to do automaticaly. I try to make it using 'sed' linux command and regex, but regex seems not working:

input:

```
CREATE TABLE "DTCUSR"."AFP_RESOURCE" 
   (    "RSC_ID" NUMBER(12,0), 
    "RSC_CLASS" VARCHAR2(5 BYTE), 
    "RSC_NAME" VARCHAR2(8 BYTE), 
    "RSC_MD5" VARCHAR2(32 BYTE), 
    "RSC_TYPE" VARCHAR2(50 BYTE), 
    "RSC_INSERT_DATE" TIMESTAMP (6)
   ) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "DTC_DATA" ;
```

wannabe out:

```
CREATE TABLE "DTCUSR"."AFP_RESOURCE" 
       (    "RSC_ID" NUMBER(12,0), 
        "RSC_CLASS" VARCHAR2(5 BYTE), 
        "RSC_NAME" VARCHAR2(8 BYTE), 
        "RSC_MD5" VARCHAR2(32 BYTE), 
        "RSC_TYPE" VARCHAR2(50 BYTE), 
        "RSC_INSERT_DATE" TIMESTAMP (6)
       );
```

linux command

```
$ sed "/(?s)SEGMENT CREATION.*?;/;/" afp_resource.sql
```

but it doesn't work, commad output is the same of input; if I try regex on Sublime or on a [regex web tool](https://regex101.com/r/ygB2pC/1), regex find what i wannt

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two step process to circumvent

```
 sed -i '/SEGMENT/,$ d' afp_resource.sql
 sed -i '$ a\);' afp_resource.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

you may try this

```
sed '/SEGMENT/,/;$/c);' afp_resource.sql
```